# 404 Issues sending form data from Wordpress page to CodeIgniter page

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have installed WP at my root directory and moved the CI application that was at the root to a sub-folder called "members." The WP pages are working just fine, but when I try to sign into the CI application, using my log in form on a WP page, I'm getting back a 404 error. I have a feeling this has something to do with routing and WP overriding things but I've been unable to figure this out so far.

.htaccess at root:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(info|info/.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(members|members/.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I wanted the info and members controllers in CI to still be accessible from WP.

I can tell the CI page is being hit because I can still redirect the browser by adding a line in the controller, yet when I try to actually post data with the form and look at the Network activity in Chrome, I can see the 404 is coming back on the page I'm posting to.

UPDATE:

Okay, I've been able to isolate this to being a routing issue, the problem is Wordpress is functional, but CodeIgniter isn't. I realize there's no modrewrite rules that apply to the /members/ directory. Here's where I'm at:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(members|members/.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /members
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: try to reset permalinks from wordpress admin. https://modernthemes.net/documentation/resetting-wordpress-permalinks/

Comment: Already did that, no dice :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a routing issue! I didn't realize I needed to put the Codeigniter specific .htaccess entries at the subfolder where the Codeigniter application resided. Of course it was that simple!